# Godaddy DNS Zone configuration

Tags: dns, records, mail-server, zone

German Mail Providers like GMX or T-Online are blocking my emails. A support guy from GMX said the a-record for mail would be missing. I added it.

Now I checked this site and got 5 warnings http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/x-invest.net/ I also added a SPF record, but there are still problems with some providers. From some providers I even did not get any mailer daemons.

My IP adress or domain is not blacklisted by any of those providers.

I am worried about doing the DNS setup wrong on my apache server, but actually it should be a copy of my setup, I used with another server before.

**Here is a screenshot of all I have at this time:**

[image: Hope the screenshot is okay for the moderation]

Maybe you could help me out, if I was missing something important or even have wrong dns record.

PS. Sorry, hope the screenshot is okay for the moderation. I was not able to copy the records - It was not my intention to spam my domain.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking your link, the only ones I'd be real concerned are (in my order of priority):

1. Primary Name Server Not Listed At Parent
2. Name Servers are on the Same Subnet
3. The Certificate is invalid

First one indicates that your nameserver listed in the SOA record is not included at the level above you:

```
x-invest.net.           86400   IN      SOA     ns1.secureserver.net. info.s50-62-56-203.secureserver.net. 2015061806 86400 7200 3600000 86400
```

Which means that the server you listed as *the* authority for your domain does not match what the internet says is *the* authority.

Second one is more an issue if you have any sort of fault tolerance worries. If the ISP drops your subnet or circuit for some reason, your sites will not resolve.

Third one is only an issue if you have customers that are concerned about the security of their connection. The big red X in the browser address bar is very discouraging to customers and their credit cards.

EDIT (answer comment):
An authoritative DNS server is one that actually contains the information being requested: [reference](http://www.dnsknowledge.com/whatis/authoritative-name-server/)

DNS being a hierarchical structure, so it follows that the chain to get to your domain needs to be complete from the top down in most cases. You can bypass that structure in some circumstances, like private DNS domains being hosted by internal corporate servers. Internal machines point to the internal DNS servers, which host domains that may not be accessible to the outside, but will also do recursive queries out to the internet as an example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i must say I am not quiet sure, if I am understanding what you mean with "the authority". Could you please be more specific on the first one, for what should I change?

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand, what is wrong with the SOA record. Should I changed seomthing on it? I guess I am not enough in to it, to understand the details.